# Estimation of main econometric techniques using matrices manually (in R)

Tags: r, econometrics, matrix

Is there any source when I can run through examples of the main econometric techniques worked out in a matrix form? (preferably in R). I tried to read the source code of functions like `lm` and `lm.fit` but it is not clear at all (source: `stats::lm` and `stats::lm.fit`).

I am looking for something similar to the OLS explained below ([source](https://thetarzan.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/calculate-ols-regression-manually-using-matrix-algebra-in-r/)) but for more complicated techniques (e.g. random effects or Tobit models). Is it available anywhere? Maybe in other programming language?

```
Create X and Y matrices for this specific regression

X = as.matrix(cbind(1,women$height))
Y = as.matrix(women$weight)

Choose beta-hat to minimize the sum of squared residuals resulting in matrix of estimated coefficients:

bh = round(solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%Y, digits=2)

Label and organize results into a data frame

beta.hat = as.data.frame(cbind(c("Intercept","Height"),bh))
names(beta.hat) = c("Coeff.","Est")
beta.hat

Calculate vector of residuals

res = as.matrix(women$weight-bh[1]-bh[2]*women$height)

Define n and k parameters
n = nrow(women)
k = ncol(X)

Calculate Variance-Covariance Matrix
VCV = 1/(n-k) * as.numeric(t(res)%*%res) * solve(t(X)%*%X)

Standard errors of the estimated coefficients

StdErr = sqrt(diag(VCV))

Calculate p-value for a t-test of coefficient significance

P.Value = rbind(2*pt(abs(bh[1]/StdErr[1]), df=n-k,lower.tail= FALSE),
2*pt(abs(bh[2]/StdErr[2]), df=n-k,lower.tail= FALSE))

Concatenate into a single data.frame

beta.hat = cbind(beta.hat,StdErr,P.Value)
beta.hat
```

Comment: lm.fit doesn't actually do the fitting. It checks arguments and sets information up before calling a C function to do the actual QR decomposition at the line: `z <- .Call(C_Cdqrls, x, y, tol, FALSE)` ... and then the rest of lm.fit is converting the output to suitable form etc. The C function "dqrls" will presumably be a conversion to C of the old fortran routine dqrls (which itself is calling linpack functions to do the work of finding the QR decomposition). Are you asking "How does QR decomposition work?" or are you asking something else?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, I am reviewing econometric techniques so I would like to see the matrix steps with toy model examples of different techniques (e.g. Tobit, random effects, FE, etc.) as in the example on OLS posted in my question. I tried to look at the source code of R packages but they have many inner functions (e.g. call.Fortran(...)). I want the code to explain the econometrics rather than to perform econometrics efficiently.

Comment: 1. Note that asking for code is generally off-topic here. Sometimes it's appropriate to ask about algorithms, but it's not generally reasonable to expect people to figure out what you were trying to achieve in your code to understand your algorithm.  2. When you say "*the* matrix steps" note that no sane person would try to use code like what you wrote to actually implement the algorithm you're trying to implement. Someone might try to do something like that to *illustrate* a linear algebra solution, but even then it makes no sense to me to round coefficients in the middle of calculation.

Comment: For example, in writing an algebraic solution to the OLS normal equations, you might write $\hat{\beta}=(X^\prime X)^{-1}X^\prime y$ but you would not use that to actually compute the parameter estimates in code implementing linear regression in that way -- it's not numerically stable. If you're only trying to understand the algebraic formulas, you need to focus on that rather than code (and many texts give algebraic solutions for particular models), even if you then use R like a calculator to actually do some illustrative computations.

Comment: So even if you do use R to play around with estimating coefficients, don't fool yourself by thinking that's how it's done in practice. For example, in linear regression the most common approach to estimation would be via QR decomposition, where the $X$ matrix is written as a product of an orthogonal matrix $Q$ (iwhere $Q^\prime Q=I$) and an upper triangular $R$, whence $(X'X)^{-1} = R^{-1}(R^\prime)^{-1}$ and then the inversion can be avoided, for example by performing forward-substitution and back-substitution.

Comment: For more complicated models, there's often no explicit solution and estimates are generally achieved by iterative algorithms.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b, I now see I was on the wrong track. I will focus on the algebra and make illustrative computations. I was totally ignorant of how the actual computations take place in statistical packages.

Comment: On the computation side, several of the books listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_statistics#Books) may prove useful (though there are equally useful books not listed there -- there are a number of decent books around).